# How to call posts from this functions code?

Tags: wordpress, function

I have a piece of code for displaying related posts by the post tag, but I don't know how to call posts in theme,
so I have this code which I have to put in my theme functions file:

```
function exe_get_related_posts_by_common_terms( $post_id, $number_posts = 0, $taxonomy = 'post_tag', $post_type = 'post' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $post_id = (int) $post_id;
    $number_posts = (int) $number_posts;

    $limit = $number_posts > 0 ? ' LIMIT ' . $number_posts : '';

    $related_posts_records = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT tr.object_id, count( tr.term_taxonomy_id ) AS common_tax_count
             FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS tr
             INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS tr2 ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tr2.term_taxonomy_id
             INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} as tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr2.term_taxonomy_id
             INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} as p ON p.ID = tr.object_id
             WHERE
                tr2.object_id = %d
                AND tt.taxonomy = %s
                AND p.post_type = %s
             GROUP BY tr.object_id
             HAVING tr.object_id != %d
             ORDER BY common_tax_count DESC" . $limit,
            $post_id, $taxonomy, $post_type, $post_id
        )
    );

    if ( count( $related_posts_records ) === 0 )
        return false;

    $related_posts = array();

    foreach( $related_posts_records as $record )
        $related_posts[] = array(
            'post_id' => (int) $record->object_id,
            'common_tax_count' => $record->common_tax_count
        );

    return $related_posts;
}
```

and now I want to call 10 posts from the above code in my single.php that can show post title and post thumbnail with the link to every post.

Answer (score 1):

try something like that:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'post_type' => 'your-posttype', // or 'any'
   'tag_slug__in' => 'your-tag',
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'posts_per_page' => 10
));
```

Then you will get latest 10 posts

Answer (score 1):

This function is very useful, people continually looking for ways to get related posts

- **What this function does:**

The code you are using is a working `function` that is returning an array of posts related to current post depending on common terms.

- **How this function works:**

You can call the function from your `single.php` file and as input you have to provide 4 info. The current post `ID`, the number of related posts to return, the `post_term` to filter the related posts (`post_tag`) and at last the `post_type`.

**Example function call:** `exe_get_related_posts_by_common_terms(get_the_ID(), 10, 'post_tag', 'post')`
*The above example will return 10 post ids as array based on current post `ID` and the `tag`*

**- Returning the post array and loop through ID's**

Now we only need a custom `wp_query` in order to loop through the `array` and format the output.

**Example wp_query:**

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post__in'      => $related_post
);
// The Query
$related_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

- **Result:**

**Full working example returning the post titles in an unordered list:**

```
<?php
$cpid = get_the_ID();  // get current post id
$related_posts = exe_get_related_posts_by_common_terms($cpid, 10, 'post_tag', 'post');
$posts_array = array_column($related_posts, 'post_id'); // new single dimension array with the ID's

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post__in'      => $posts_array
);
// The Query
$related_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($related_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<ul>
<?php while ($related_query->have_posts()) : $related_query->the_post(); ?>
<li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can now set the look and fill as you like

Comment: thank you @kaize but the code only sorts last posts. I test in local

Comment: You are right. I have a typo, the array is `$related_posts` and in the query i used `$related_post` missed an "s". Then my second mistake is that I have to convert the returning array in order to get one single dimensional array with the  ID's. I have updated my answer with the corrections